Is there a reason to use a reference variable other than in functions?
As far as I can tell, unless it

involves a function that returns a reference or takes a reference, or
involves a class,

there's no real reason to use it. I see no purpose for them which would not be fulfilled better using either a pointer or the original variable.

Counterexample: auto &foo = some[deeply][complex].expression if you need to repeatedly do something to a value deeply nested inside a data structure.

@Botje, I see what you mean, there.

Adding to what @Botje said, even for simpler expressions it can be useful. For instance, when iterating over something like std::map, you end up with a std::pair. Instead of using it->first and it->second everywhere, it can be helpful to use a reference which gives you a meaningful variable name to work with. That makes code easier to read.

I use references in range based for loops often.

Your edit changed the question quite significantly. "There is no reason to use references unless it involves a class" means basically 99% of C++ is a reasonable use for references.

@paddy you mean the destructuring auto& [key, value] = ... ?

@Botje even without the destructuring if you do something like for (auto& x : map) { something(x.first, x.second); } you're not invoking a copy operation.

Very frequently, I use a reference in a range-based for-loop: for (auto& val : container) { val += something(); }

Yeah, all that, and also spare a thought for those of us who still have to work with older language standards and don't even have range-based loops.

If you have a complicated expression, assigning it to a reference with a descriptive name can improve the readability of your code.

One nice thing about a reference is that you don’t have to worry about the possibility of it being  NULL, since references can never be NULL.

Consider the following trivial program. In the A b case, the constructor is called. In the second A c = b; line, the copy constructor is called. In the last case, no copy or move happens at all.
Whether this is beneficial depends on how costly a copy operation is. Obviously for this trivial example it doesn't really matter, but imagine your class/struct allocates a large amount of memory, and then on a copy has to copy all of that state to a new object. That might substantially impact performance and scaling. Assigning to a reference would not have that impact.
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct A {
    A() { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    ~A() { cout << "Destructor\n"; }
    A(const A& a) { cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    A(A&& a) { cout << "Move constructor\n"; }
    A& operator=(const A& a) { cout << "Copy assignment\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&& a) { cout << "Move assignment\n"; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    A b;
    A c = b;
    A& d = b;
}

Suggested reading: rule of three/five/zero.
